# Windows 10 Update Failure from Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

In my C dive i have 15.3 GB free available space. Get Windows Icon shows that my laptop is fully compatible for windows 10 update.
[image]
[image]

but it has been the third time it failed to update my pc from windows 8.1 to windows 10 :( and i am highly disappointed :(

Here is the error message:
[image]

What that error code means and what would be a fix for this problem?

Comment: Did you search for `80072EE2` ?  I find lots of google hits, mostly suggesting it happens when the update servers are overloaded.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, and i have cleaned-up all the old updates but still having this error message!